# PHP echo only once to display only one image

Tags: php, for-loop, wordpress

I'm trying to figure out how to write a code to display the image only once inside the loop.

For example in Wordpress

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

inside that loop I just want to place one image on the first post only.

I only know how to do that in C and C++ but I don't know how is that work on PHP?

Here is what I did to achieve this. Thanks to @Jack.

First I declare a variable before my Wordpress post loop start.

```
<?php

$displayed = false;

?>
```

Then I have the code that @Jack suggest with a small modification.

```
<?php

$image = 'your image URL';

    if (!$displayed)
    {
         echo $image;
         $displayed = true;

    }

    ?>
```

And that's it now I can have my picture show only once!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put a conditional inside the loop.

```
$displayed = false;
while ($someVariable)
{
    if (!$displayed)
    {
         echo $image;
         $displayed = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: When is the condition of while will be false?

Comment: What is your loop supposed to do?

Comment: Well I have like 10 post on Wordpress right? so I just want this ads for example to display only once not all the posts.

Comment: I don't know why it still display for all the posts :(

Comment: So the image is an ad? I don't get why you would need to put that in a loop.  Why can't you just have the `echo $image` outside the loop if you only want it once? It'd help if you post some code of what you're doing.

Comment: I got it work now Thanks! I just declare that variables before the Wordpress loop and now it only show once.!